# how to paste words on search(c-s) in Emacs

Tags: emacs

On editing, I can use `command+c` and `command+v` to copy and paste words on MacOS.
However, when I want to search some word, I copy the word from other,
then, I use `c-s` and want to paste the word by `command+v`.

but it shows `mark set`..but not paste the word.
So, How can I paste word when I push `c-s`?

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the isearch minibuffer, you can use `M-y` (`option-y` on Mac) to paste text to the end of the search string. It runs `isearch-yank-kill`. For more details, please refer to http://www.emacswiki.org/emacs/IncrementalSearch.